# What is the correct way to send key value pair in JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, post

I'm trying to do POST in PHP. In the document, they mentioned the format as below.

```
{
"EmailAddress": "john.smith@acmeconsulting.co",
"ActivityEvent": 112,
"ActivityNote": "Note for the activity",
"ActivityDateTime": "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss",
"FirstName": "John",
"LastName" : "Smith",
"Phone" : "+919845098450",
"Score": 10
}
```

I'm new to PHP. I tried the following ways to create a key value pair.None of the example posted below do a POST on server[ I couldn't find my POST update on the server i.e leadsquared cloud].

My sample data. I used the below sample data in the examples mentioned here.

```
$firstName='Test5';
$activityEvent=201;
$emailAddress='test10@test.com';
$activityNote='Note note note';
$phone='9551653808';
$date='2015-07-21 12:48:10';
```

Example 1 : `

```
  $data_string = '[
        {"ActivityEvent": "'.$activityEvent.'"},
        {"EmailAddress": "'.$emailAddress.'"},
        {"ActivityNote": "'.$activityNote.'"},
        {"Phone": "'.$phone.'"},
        {"ActivityDateTime","'.$date.'"}
      ]';
```

Example 2 :

```
      $data_string['ActivityEvent']=$activityEvent;
      $data_string['EmailAddress']=$emailAddress;
      $data_string['ActivityNote']=$activityNote;
      $data_string['Phone']=$phone;
      $data_string['ActivityDateTime']=$date;
```

Example 3 :

```
          $datastring = array(
          'ActivityEvent' => $activityEvent,
          'EmailAddress' => $emailAddress,
          'ActivityNote' => $activityNote,
          'Phone' => $phone,
          'ActivityDateTime' => $date);
```

Once the example is right, I'm posting the datastring to the following code.

```
try
{
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                      'Content-Type:application/json',
                      'Content-Length:'.strlen($data_string)
                      ));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
 curl_close($curl);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are using  'Content-Type:application/json' you need to provide json array not a php array so
first  get a php formatted array by

```
$datastring=
array(
"EmailAddress"=> "john.smith@acmeconsulting.co",
"ActivityEvent"=> 112,
"ActivityNote"=> "Note for the activity",
"ActivityDateTime"=> "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss",
"FirstName"=> "John",
"LastName" => "Smith",
"Phone" => "+919845098450",
"Score"=> 10
);
```

then use php json encoding function as

```
$value=json_encode($datastring)
echo $value;
$value will be your json encoded array
{
"EmailAddress":"john.smith@acmeconsulting.co",
"ActivityEvent":112,
"ActivityNote":"Note for the activity","ActivityDateTime":"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss",
"FirstName":"John",
"LastName":"Smith",
"Phone":"+919845098450",
"Score":10
}
```

replace $datastring to $value in your code as

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                      'Content-Type:application/json',
                      'Content-Length:'.strlen($value)
                      ));
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$datastring = array(
  'ActivityEvent' => $activityEvent,
  'EmailAddress' => $emailAddress,
  'ActivityNote' => $activityNote,
  'Phone' => $phone,
  'ActivityDateTime' => $date
);
json_encode($datastring);
```

refer [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) link.

you only need to change

```
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
```

to

```
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data_string));
```

Comment: I tried this. This also doesn't do a POST on server.